# Badges implementation issue

Tags: java, implementation

I am designing a website using JSF + EJBS + JPA, etc.  JAVA EE 6 to sum up.

You can create an article, and over time if it meets certain conditions (say 1000 views) it's awarded a "1000 views badge."

The problem arises when I want to create new badges dynamically. I  have a badge entity class, and all badges are fetched from a database. How can I dynamically establish conditions for a badge to be awarded to an article, since the behavior depends on each instance rather than its type?

For instance the business logic for evaluating the meeting requirements for a '1000 views badge' is very different from the one used in a 'best rated article of the week' etc.  Also, what if the number of badges grows?

I can't just extend a class because it doesnt make sense, so I figured I'm not looking at this the right way.

Any thoughts on how would you implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Implement a @Singleton, which has a method running once in a period(once per hour or per 24 hours). It will have a collection of classes to check the posts for some conditions. If you want a new badge, just add a class.

```
@Singleton
public class Watchdog implements Serializable {
    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The em. */
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private List<PostChecker> checkers = new ArrayList<PostChecker>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
      checkers.add(new ThousandViewChecker());
      checkers.add(new PopularPostChecker());
      ....


    }

    @Schedule(...)
    public void monitor() {
       for (PostChecker checker : checkers) {
          checker.check(em);
       }        
    }

}
```

If you don't want to add a class each time, create some xml file with the rules of badge awarding and create a factory of checkers, which will construct their badge rules using those xml files. Then to add a badge you will need just to add an xml.

Comment: How would you implement it on xml? It's not an attribute but rather java code that has to resolve to true or false. Can I execute a String?